# How to install simplenote in opensuse?

Tags: opensuse

I have downloaded simplenote simplenote's portal. The tar.gz version, but I couldn't install it on OpenSuse 13.1

Any Idea of the steps needed to install it ??

Answer (score 0):

There is executable file in the tar.gz called `Simplenote`.
You could start it from terminal with `/path/Simplenote-linux-x64/Simplenote` (I don't have a Linux GUI right now)
If that works, you could move the folder to /opt link that to /usr/bin with `ln -s /opt/Simplenote-linux-x64/Simplenote /usr/bin/` then you could start it from terminal with `Simplenote`

**Edit:**
Just tested on my Linux-Mint Laptop, should work the same on your openSUSE 13.1 (actually this openSUSE version is end of life).

1. Download Simplenote
2. `sudo tar xvzf Simplenote-linux-x64.1.0.8.tar.gz --directory=/opt/`
3. `sudo ln -s /opt/Simplenote-linux-x64.1.0.8 /usr/bin/`
4. Now you could start that program in Terminal with `Simplenote &` or wit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in "Simplenote".

Comment: Ok, I will try It and give feedback.